# Is there any way for 3rd party apps installed on Android phone to hack data between Android phone and Android Wear watch?

Tags: android, security, wear-os

I'm investigating security of Android Wear.

Is there any way for 3rd party apps installed on Android phone to hack communicating data between Android phone and Android Wear watch ?

If I want to send secure data(just text string) from android phone to android wear(watch), what can I do for that ?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: All data passed by wireless is hackable.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Pedro. actually I want to know whether 3rd android apps(malicious apps) installed on my android phone could hack data passed to my connected android wear device(watch) or not.. Is it possible? If so, could you let me know how it is possible ?(mechanism using android sdk api)

Comment: @jaemoon.hwang it would't have to read it when it is being passed, malicious apps that have proper access can read the data directly from your phone, no?

Comment: @starvator I am wondering whether malicious apps of phone read(or hack) "the data which are being passed to android wear" or not. If it is possible, I want to know how malicious apps read it.

Comment: @starvator If "the data to be passed to android wear" can not be read by malicious apps on the phone, is it impossible for "the data which are being passed to android wear" to hack ?

Comment: @starvator For example, if "the data to be passed to android wear" is just text string to be sent to android wear by using NotificationManagerCompat, is it possible to hack it ?

Comment: So, if I want to send secure data(just text string) from android phone to android wear(watch), what can I do for that ?

Answer (score 2):

When using the Data Layer API, messages can only be sent between apps running on the wearable and phone that contain the same package name, and the same version. So Google Play Services makes sure that messages are delivered to the correct app running on the other device.

This is why it is so important to get the package and version name the same when embedding the wearable APK inside the phone APK - if you get it wrong it won't install it to the wearable.

It is not possible for application A on a phone to communicate with application B on a wearable.

Comment: Dear Wayne Piekarski,thank you for your answer. So data through the data layer api which you commented is safe from any malicious apps ? for examples, any malicious apps cannot hack(or intercept, cath)  the data content ? thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

If they are connected, yes, it is possible. You can be hacked by just opening a website, and anything through wireless is connected in a way. Usually tho, you wont be hacked unless they ask for too many permissions, then you should not be downloading it in the first place. If you skip through it though, they are able to get info from your phone which is connected to your android wear. Be careful with third party apps.